# Use of lock keyword and the new async functionality of C# 5.0

Tags: c#, async-ctp, c#-5.0

Is it still necessary to use the lock keyword on resources like SQL Compact database in methods called with async (AsyncCtpLibrary.dll)? As i understand from the talk given by Anders, the async processing all happens within the same thread, so they shouldn't be a need for it, or am I wrong? I cannot find any info on this anywhere on the internet at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: If multiple instances of the async thread can happen I would imagine it would be required.  Otherwise in theory you could attempt to update the same row/col and the end result would be a race condition.  One could argue you simply use a lock before using the async method.

Comment: I don't know anything about the SQL Compact Database, but I don't think it's relevant to correctness how many threads anything is running on.  If something needed a mutex to be safely reentrant before, it probably needs a mutex to be safely reentrant now, whether one thread or many are doing the re-entering.

Comment: What I meant by multiple instances of the async thread would be the same and/or similar query being done multiple times in a short amount of time.  I should also add there isn't a C# 5.0 at this time to my knowlege.  There is C# 4.5 in Dev Preview, the ASYNC CTP will be part of a future C# revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK async is based on the TPL and Tasks - and so no they won't be running on the same thread every time (or continue on the same thread) and yes you have to design with concurency in mind still. Async only helps you to put the pieces together in a much nicer way.

To be clear: everything inside your methods (if started only once) will run in a thread at a time but if you share resources you will have to think on locking or other synchronization methods just as you used to do all the time.

If you can go for immutable data - this way you can strip all this to a mere minimum, but you allway have to remember that your processes will run on many threads (dispatch for UI comes to mind).